How to create a redis cluster using docker with 6 nodes deployed in 2 different servers
I need to create a redis cluster environment in docker with 6 redis nodes deployed in 2 different servers, each with 3 nodes.
sample docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
networks:
  redis-cluster:
    driver: overlay
    external: true

services:
  redis-node-1:
    image: redis:7.0
    container_name: redis-node-1
    volumes:
      - ./config/redis-node1.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./data/redis-node1:/data
      - ./logs/redis-node1:/var/log/redis
    ports:
      - "7001:6379"
      - "17001:16379"
    networks:
      redis-cluster:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.11
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

redis-node1.conf
port 6379
bind 0.0.0.0
cluster-announce-ip 172.18.0.11
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-7001.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
dir /var/lib/redis/7001
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-7001.log
pidfile /var/run/redis-7001.pid
requirepass DevRedis01
masterauth DevRedis01
cluster-require-full-coverage no

I have created a network using following settings
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <server-ip>
docker swarm join --token <your-token> <manager-ip>:2377
docker network create --driver overlay --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 redis-cluster

Getting error as follows while using docker-compose
usert@ugat:sudo docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.
 
Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.
 
To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.
 
Starting redis-node-5 ... error
Starting redis-node-4 ...
Starting redis-node-6 ...
Starting redis-node-4 ... error
ERROR: for redis-node-5  Cannot start service redis-node-5: network redis-cluster not found
 
Starting redis-node-6 ... error
 
ERROR: for redis-node-6  Cannot start service redis-node-6: network redis-cluster not found
 
ERROR: for redis-node-5  Cannot start service redis-node-5: network redis-cluster not found
 
ERROR: for redis-node-4  Cannot start service redis-node-4: network redis-cluster not found
 
ERROR: for redis-node-6  Cannot start service redis-node-6: network redis-cluster not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

is there anything I missed while creating the network?

maybe you just need to call the network redis-cluster in the docker command instead of redis-cluster-net? I would also look into that warning in the beginning about not using compose with swarm.

I just pasted the template that's why the cluster name is different in the docker command...swarm is not needed for this implementation...that's why I skipped that part

if you don't run the code with swarm in it, I would edit it out of the question

for the communication between 2 nodes using the same docker network, i used this swarm...is there any alternative

I'm not really a docker expert. If it's communication between two containers I know you don't need swarm. Can use docker compose with multiple containers and they will talk through a network. But with nodes I don't know

it will work perfectly on a single server...but facing issues while trying with multiple servers
